# Uploading files to FTP using PHP

Tags: php, forms, file, ftp, submit

please, I really need your help. i have problems with **uploading files to FTP server with using a PHP form**. this form was o.k., but my hosting provider recently changed the version of PHP and from this moment, I have big problems. the communication with database is working, but file transfer not. please, can anyone advise me? **thank you very much for your help!**

**the form:**

```
<?  include('./config.php');    ?>
<?
    $spojeni = @MySQL_Connect($se, $uz, $he);
    $db = @MySQL_Select_DB($DB);

?>


<FORM METHOD="POST" action="ins_info.php" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<TABLE>

<TR><TD><u><b>Upload a file:</b></u></TD></TR>
<TR>
<TD><b>Title:</b></TD>
<TD><INPUT TYPE="TEXT" NAME="titulek_form"></INPUT></TD>
</TR>
<TR>
<TD><b>Date:</b></TD>
<TD><INPUT TYPE="TEXT" NAME="datum_form"></INPUT></TD>
</TR>
<TR>
<TD><b>File:</b></TD>
<TD><INPUT TYPE="FILE" ACCEPT="*/*" SIZE="33" NAME="soubor"></INPUT></TD>
</TR>
<TR>
<TD><INPUT TYPE="SUBMIT" NAME="Odeslat" VALUE="Add to database"></INPUT></TD>
</TR>
</TABLE>

</FORM>
```

**and the file ins_info.php:** (the file from a form gets a new name, for example info1234.pdf -- but now is working only writing to a database -- the result is, that I get info1234. (without file on FTP and without filetype in a database)

```
<?  include('./config.php') ?>
<?
    @Set_Time_Limit(0);

    $INI_ADMIN_PASSWORD = $_GET[INI_ADMIN_PASSWORD];
    $INI_ftp_server = $_GET[INI_ftp_server];  
    $INI_info_path = $_GET[INI_info_path];                                  
    $INI_server_info_path = $_GET[INI_server_info_path];
    $INI_server_tmp_path = $_GET[INI_server_tmp_path];
    $INI_ftp_user = $_GET[INI_ftp_user];
    $INI_ftp_pass = $_GET[INI_ftp_pass];                               
    $spojeni_ftp = $_GET[spojeni_ftp];
    $soubor = $_FILES["soubor"]["name"];

    $titulek_form = $_POST["titulek_form"];
    $datum_form = $_POST["datum_form"]; 
    $DatumInt = $_POST["DatumInt"];
    $MaxID = $_POST["MaxID"];     
    $prenos_info = $_POST["prenos_info"];
    $vloz_info = $_POST["vloz_info"];   
    $jmeno = $_POST["jmeno"];
    $vyber2 = $_POST["vyber2"];
    $datum2 = $_POST["datum2"];
    $nazev = $_POST["nazev"]; 
    $soubor_name = $_POST["soubor_name"];
    $cislo = $_POST["cislo"];
    $jmeno =  $_POST["jmeno"];*

IF($PASSWORD==$INI_ADMIN_PASSWORD):

    $spojeni = @MySQL_Connect($se, $uz, $he);
    $db = @MySQL_Select_DB($DB);

    $vyber2 = @MySQL_Query("SELECT Max(ID) FROM info");
    $MaxID = @MySQL_Result($vyber2, 0) +1;

    $titulek_form = HTMLSpecialChars($titulek_form);
    $datum_form = HTMLSpecialChars($datum_form);

    $datum2 = Explode(".", $datum_form);

    $DatumInt = MkTime(0,0,0, $datum2[1], $datum2[0], $datum2[2]);

    $jmeno = "info";

    $i = 1;

    do
{
         if($i==1) $jmeno_old = $jmeno;
         $jmeno = $jmeno_old;
         $nazev = Explode(".", $soubor_name);
         SRand((double)MicroTime()*1e6);
         $cislo = Rand (1, 9999);
//       $nazev[0] .= $cislo;
         $jmeno .= $cislo.".".$nazev[1];
         $i++;
}
    While(@File_Exists("$INI_info_path$jmeno"));


    $vloz_info = @MySQL_Query("INSERT INTO info VALUES ('$MaxID', '$titulek_form', '$datum_form', '$jmeno', '$DatumInt')");


// ***  FTP start


        @chdir("$INI_server_tmp_path");                                                     // docasny adresar
        $spojeni_ftp = @ftp_connect("$INI_ftp_server");                         // pripojeni k FTP serveru
        @ftp_login($spojeni_ftp, "$INI_ftp_user", "$INI_ftp_pass");                             // prihlaseni k FTP serveru

        $prenos_info = @ftp_put($spojeni_ftp, "$INI_info_ftp_path$jmeno", "$soubor", FTP_BINARY);       // kam se ma soubor ulozit

        @chdir("$INI_server_home_path");                                                // nastaveni domovskeho adresare
        @ftp_close($spojeni_ftp);                                                               // odhlaseni od FTP serveru


// *** FTP end

    Header("Location: status.php?prenos_info=$prenos_info&vloz_info=$vloz_info");
?>
<?
ELSE:
    Echo "<p>Error</b></p>";
ENDIF;
?>
```

**folders have 777 rights**. I'm be doubtful about POST and GET methods in the beginning of the file.

Comment: I'm a bit worried about security because you're getting the ftp login credentials from the $_GET variables? Is this suppose to be? Normally, you would send login credentials through POST.

Comment: thank you very much, I recently changed it... but I don't know, how to fix the problem with file transfer.

Comment: Does this php file even parse? I see you have a couple of characters in the file on a place where PHP doesn't expect them to be there.

Comment: yes, there is no error message... only a file is not transfer...